# Odds of both parents having green eyes

Tags: probability, statistics

If we know that parents who both have green eyes have an 88% chance of having a child with green eyes, while parents who both have brown eyes only have a 8 percent chance of having a child with green eyes. 
We also know that 72% of the world population has brown eyes and 2% of the world has green eyes.

Jack has green eyes. What are the odds both his parents have green eyes?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: That does not look like sufficient information.  It only provides probabilities for when both parents have the same coloured eyes.  What for the other three combinations?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be 88%?

Comment: @BadrB - It is not 88% because brown eyed parents can have green eyed children too.  Imagine 99.999999% of the world population have brown eyes.  Then Jack is very likely to the one of these green eyed children of brown eyed parents.

Comment: If $72\%$ of the world population has brown eyes then presumably between $44\%$ and $72\%$ of couples both have brown eyes, so between $3.52\%$ and $5.76\%$ of all children have green-eyes themselves while having both parents with brown-eyes.  But apparently only $2\%$ of the world has green eyes.  Or something else is going on